# cakephp how to break user come back to login page or register page by click back in browser

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, authentication

I'm Newbie in cakephp and I create register page and login page
this problem
when I login success and redirect to dashboard when I click back in browser
it's back to login page
Please tell us ways to fix this problem.

Comment: nothing about this page makes any sense but I suspect you need to lower the security level

Comment: hey I set security level = medium . What should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes... the evil back button.  Web developers have been trying to circumvent it since the Stone Age.
The most common way of disabling it is to use client side Javascript to purge the history.